# Confusion in Nested loop in sql plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using `IF` condition in sql*plus but cannot access the variable of the outer loop in the inner loop. Here's my statement:

```
DECLARE
  LOOPSTART INT;
  LOOPEND INT;
  VALUE INT;
  CURSOR EMPID IS (SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP);
BEGIN
  SELECT EMPNO INTO LOOPSTART FROM emp WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
  SELECT MAX(EMPNO) INTO LOOPEND FROM EMP;

  FOR COUNT IN LOOPSTART..LOOPEND LOOP
    BEGIN
      FOR EMPID1 IN EMPID LOOP
        IF (EMPID1.EMPNO != COUNT) THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LOOPSTART);
          exit;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

and this error came:

*ORA-06550: line 13, column 22:
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a SQL statement only
ORA-06550: line 13, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

1. DECLARE
2. LOOPSTART INT;
3. LOOPEND INT;

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: rename the count to something else like count1

Comment: thnx... I was finding the error from half an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the varialble count used to count_my or any thing else you like

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is a keywork rename the COUNT it will work